# How to efficiently search a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a dictionary with only 4 keys (`mydictionary`) and a list (`mynodes`) as follows.

```
    mydictionary = {0: {('B', 'E', 'G'), ('A', 'E', 'G'), ('A', 'E', 'F'), ('A', 'D', 'F'), ('C', 'D', 'F'), ('C', 'E', 'F'), ('A', 'D', 'G'), ('C', 'D', 'G'), ('C', 'E', 'G'), ('B', 'E', 'F')}, 
1: {('A', 'C', 'G'), ('E', 'F', 'G'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('A', 'F', 'G'), ('A', 'B', 'G'), ('B', 'D', 'F'), ('C', 'F', 'G'), ('A', 'C', 'E'), ('D', 'E', 'G'), ('B', 'F', 'G'), ('B', 'C', 'G'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'F'), ('B', 'D', 'G'), ('B', 'C', 'F'), ('A', 'D', 'E'), ('C', 'D', 'E'), ('A', 'C', 'F'), ('A', 'B', 'E'), ('B', 'C', 'E'), ('D', 'F', 'G')}, 
2: {('B', 'D', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')}, 
3: {('A', 'B', 'C')}}

mynodes = ['E', 'D', 'G', 'F', 'B', 'A', 'C']
```

I am checking how many times each node in `mynodes` list is in each key of `mydictionary`. For example, consider the above dictionary and list.

The output should be;

```
{'E': [(0, 6), (1, 8), (2, 1), (3, 0)], 
'D': [(0, 4), (1, 8), (2, 3), (3, 0)], 
'G': [(0, 5), (1, 10), (2, 0), (3, 0)], 
'F': [(0, 5), (1, 10), (2, 0), (3, 0)], 
'B': [(0, 2), (1, 9), (2, 3), (3, 1)], 
'A': [(0, 4), (1, 9), (2, 1), (3, 1)], 
'C': [(0, 4), (1, 9), (2, 1), (3, 1)]}
```

For example, consider `E`. It appears 6 times in `0` key, 8 times in `1` key, 2 times in `2` key and 0 times in `3` key.

My current code is as follows.

```
    triad_class_for_nodes = {}

    
    for node in mynodes:
        temp_list = []
                
        for key, value in mydictionary.items():                
            temp_counting = 0
            
            for triad in value:
                #print(triad[0])
                if node in triad:
                    temp_counting = temp_counting + 1
            temp_list.append(tuple((key, temp_counting)))
    
        triad_class_for_nodes.update({node: temp_list})
    print(triad_class_for_nodes)
```

This works fine with the small dictionary values.

However, in my real dataset, I have millions of tuples in the value list for each of my 4 keys in my dictionary. Hence, my existing code is really inefficient and takes days to run.

When I search on how to make this more efficient I came accross this question ([Fastest way to search a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993621/fastest-way-to-search-a-list-in-python)), which suggests to make the list of values to a set. I tried this as well. However, it also takes days to run.

I am just wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this in python. **I am happy to transform my existing data formats into different structures (such as `pandas dataframe`) to make things more efficient.**

A small sample of `mydictionary` and `mynodes` is attached below for testing purposes. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15Faa78xlNAYLPvqS3cKM1v8bV1HQzW2W?usp=sharing

- mydictionary: see triads.txt

  `with open("triads.txt", "r") as file:` 
        `mydictionary = ast.literal_eval(file.read)`

mynodes: see nodes.txt

```
with open("nodes.txt", "r") as file:  
   mynodes = ast.literal_eval(file.read)
```

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tag `pandas`, first we need convert your dict to `pandas` dataframe , then we `stack` it , and using `crosstab`

```
s=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydictionary,'index').stack()


s = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).stack()
pd.crosstab(s.index.get_level_values(0),s)
col_0  A  B  C  D  E   F   G
row_0                       
0      4  2  4  4  6   5   5
1      9  9  9  8  8  10  10
2      1  3  1  3  1   0   0
3      1  1  1  0  0   0   0
```

Update

```
s=pd.crosstab(s.index.get_level_values(0), s).stack().reset_index()

s[['row_0',0]].apply(tuple,1).groupby(s['col_0']).agg(list).to_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think it is more efficient than my existing solution?

Comment: @Emi in term of efficient I think it will depend on your data size , but pd.crosstab the data have better look than the dict of list of tuple

Comment: Thanks. I will run your code for my actual dataset and will let you know how it performed :)

Comment: Just wondering how I can transform your final output into something like this: `{'E': [(0, 6), (1, 8), (2, 1), (3, 0)], 
'D': [(0, 4), (1, 8), (2, 3), (3, 0)], 
'G': [(0, 5), (1, 10), (2, 0), (3, 0)], 
'F': [(0, 5), (1, 10), (2, 0), (3, 0)], 
'B': [(0, 2), (1, 9), (2, 3), (3, 1)], 
'A': [(0, 4), (1, 9), (2, 1), (3, 1)], 
'C': [(0, 4), (1, 9), (2, 1), (3, 1)]}` Please let me know your thoughts :)

Comment: I did not get a lot of performance gain through this solution. However, it is a clean and nice code and I like it compared to my code :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using pandas, you could do this with Counter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter,defaultdict
from itertools import product
counts = Counter((c,k) for k,v in mydictionary.items() for t in v for c in t )
result = defaultdict(list)
for c,k in product(mynodes,mydictionary):
    result[c].append((k,counts[(c,k)]))

print(result)
{'E': [(0, 6), (1, 8), (2, 1), (3, 0)],
 'D': [(0, 4), (1, 8), (2, 3), (3, 0)],
 'G': [(0, 5), (1, 10), (2, 0), (3, 0)],
 'F': [(0, 5), (1, 10), (2, 0), (3, 0)],
 'B': [(0, 2), (1, 9), (2, 3), (3, 1)],
 'A': [(0, 4), (1, 9), (2, 1), (3, 1)],
 'C': [(0, 4), (1, 9), (2, 1), (3, 1)]}
```

Counter will manage counting instances for each combination of mydictionary key and node.  You can then use these counts to create the expected output.

**EDIT** Expanded counts line:

```
counts = Counter()                          # initialize Counter() object
for key,tupleSet in mydictionary.items():   # loop through dictionary
    for tupl in tupleSet:                   # loop through tuple set of each key
        for node in tupl:                   # loop through node character in each tuple
            counts[(node,key]] += 1         # count 1 node/key pair
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. Do you think that this is more efficient than my code? :) I will also test it in my dataset and let you know.

Comment: It would be great appreciated if you could help me to expand this line `counts = Counter((c,k) for k,v in mydictionary.items() for t in v for c in t )`.
`