# Search in list of string or a big string, which one is faster?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, compare

trying to capture console output and find keyword in that,
which approach should be faster?
for example: trying to run "ls" command through python and check a keyword is there in the console output

1st Approach
having a list of string and then search in each string

```
list_output = [ "abc", "def", "xyz"]
for i in list_output:
    if "ab" in i:
        print "found"
        break
```

Please note: Each item in list_output might be a big string itself

2nd Approach
having a big string and search a sub string in the big string

```
string_output = "abcdefxyz"
if "ab" in S:
    print "found"
```

Please note: string_output could be a huge string

Need to stop search as soon as first occurrence is found, no need to search entire string or list further

Comment: I think first approach is fine. Second approach can cause memory issues.

Comment: You don't want to use the second because with some bad input, e.g. `efx` you could get "found" when it would probably be wrong.

Comment: how big are these "big string"s?  millions or billions of bytes?  what are you splitting them on?  if this is output of `ls` I'd not expect it to be pretty small (normally much less than a MB), also why not use use `pathlib`?

Comment: "ls" is just a sample command, it could be any linux command.
And yes, output of those command should not go beyond 1 MB
,I am splitting the on "\n"

Comment: Instead of piping the output of `ls` straight to python, why not pass it through `grep` first to extract the terms you're looking for? It's bound to be faster at matching strings than anything you could write in python.

Comment: Need to show the entire output and then print message if the keyword is in the output

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993621/fastest-way-to-search-a-list-in-python) using your second approach is much faster than the first one, because the first approach sets up a hash table on the fly, and just does a linear search.

Also (still referring to the link above) if using sequence is a must, `set` is better that `list`

Comment: Did you read the question? You reference an answer using a set, but then reference the OP idea which is one long string.

Comment: @GuyCoder yes I've read the question. and the link has multiple answers. check out the second answer. its about strings

Comment: this this approach there is an overhead to convert the big string in to set.
Could you please provide an example