# Python lookup search in a list: multiple search criteria, return value required

Tags: python, csv

I have a relatively large csv file containing a list of companies, products, and prices. The ordering of the data is not guaranteed (i.e. not sorted):

```
csv#1 (big file)        
... 
CompanyA     productB     0
CompanyA     productA     0
CompanyA     productC     0
CompanyB     productA     0
CompanyB     productB     0
CompanyB     productC     0
...
```

Some of the entries in "csv#1" have bad data (zeroes). I have a second csv containing only the names from csv#1 that had bad data (and their corrected data). The ordering of this csv is by descending price:

```
csv#2 (small file - subset of csv#1)        
CompanyA     productC     15
CompanyA     productB     10
CompanyA     productA     5
CompanyB     productA     3
CompanyB     productB     2
CompanyB     productC     1
```

**I want to iterate through csv#1 and if the combination of Company + product is in csv#2, overwrite with csv#2 price.**

I know I can do this by brute force, iterating over csv#2 for every row in csv#1. I could even optimize by loading csv#2 into an array and removing entries once they are found (each combination will show up exactly once in csv#1). But I am certain there must be a better way.

I found some references indicating that `sets` are a more efficient way to do these kinds of lookup searches:

[Most efficient way for a lookup/search in a huge list (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701173/most-efficient-way-for-a-lookup-search-in-a-huge-list-python)

[Fastest way to search a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993621/fastest-way-to-search-a-list-in-python)

But I am not sure how to apply `sets` to my example. How to I structure a `set` here, given the multiple search columns, and the need to return a value if there is a match? Or is there a better approach than `sets`?

Comment: Your example data appears to be sorted.  Is that the case in your actual data?

Comment: @femtoRgon - Sorry if my simplified data is misleading. The data is sorted, but by descending price, not by any of the name fields. I will revise the question to show this more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you could technically associate a key with a value, why not use a dictionary? It has constant lookup time O(1) instead of O(N) for a list. It is similar to a set except for the concept of key value pair.

```
csv1_dict = {  ...,
            "CompanyA productA" : 0,
            "CompanyA productB" : 0,
            ...
            }

csv2_dict = { ...,
            "CompanyA productA" : 10,
              ...
            }
for key,value in csv2_dict.iteritems():
    try:
        csv1_dict[key] = csv2_dict[key]
    except:
        #Key not in csv1
```

If you can guarantee that Company products in csv2 are in csv1, feel free to remove the try block.

Comment: Would I iterate though the csv files to build the dicionary? Do I physically join "CompanyA productA" as a string to make the key? Do I really need a dict for csv1? If I need to iterate through it to build the dict, maybe I could just use that iteration to do the comparison (once I have a dict in place for csv2)?

Comment: You would have to iterate through the csv regardless, so yes you could just load csv2 as a dict and then when iterating through csv1, just insert a try block and attempt to write the new value to your output, and in the except write the original value. As for a key, it can be whatever you want it to be, as long as it is unique.

Comment: I think dict lookup takes O(lg(N)) not O(1), because it uses a binary search on hash codes

Comment: Looks like the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) lists it as O(N) worst case assuming you have some implementation of python with a bad hash algorithm for dict that results in chaining, but shows O(1) on average (which is what a good hash function should have).

Comment: iteritems is now `items()` in python3

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest loading csv#2 into a dictionary which is actually a hash table and queries are fast

Set is also a hash table without values, but you have values here

The keys of dict are tuples of (companyName, productName) , and values are prices

Then iterate over csv#1 and check if the correction dict has the key for that company name (use has_key, or simple get the key in try ... except block) and if there was, do the fix using associated price value

Comment: I don't think company names will work as keys, because they are not unique. Can I use a tuple as a key (company, product)? Or would I need to join company+product into a key string?

Comment: Yes, Tuples are okay for using as keys. (FYI, Lists are not usable as keys because list is not hashable)

Comment: I updated the answer (sorry now I realize that price for a company doesn't make sense, I didn't notice the meaning of names, just saw the logic! :D )