# Fastest way to perform Find method respecting order in Python

Tags: python-2.7, list, python-3.x, indexing, find

I have two lists :

- List1 is 1x4000, a list of **Ordered** features (and order is crucial for the rest of my code)
- List2 is of random length and is the list I need to extract the features from.

The required output is:

- A numpy list of size 1x4000 of binaries, so that `feature_list[i]` is equal to 1 if the i*th* feature of `List1` is present in `List2`, 0 otherwise.

So far I am using the below code:

```
feature_list = np.array([1 if (feat[1] in List2) else 0 for feat in List1])
```

But as you can imagine, this takes a very long time when called thousand times.

These threads [Stackoverflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701173/most-efficient-way-for-a-lookup-search-in-a-huge-list-python), [Stackoverflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993621/fastest-way-to-search-a-list-in-python) recommend the use of a `dict` or a `set`, but I need to call this indexing thousands of times and it has to be in the same **order** everytime.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So you have two lists, `list1` and `list2`. Your implementation checks 4000 times (the length of `list1`) if a given element is in `list2`.

A first improvement would be to make `list2` shorter by converting it to a set (since this will remove duplicates). As you see in the example, in this case the execution time has been reduced from 102 ms to 2.42 ms.

```
In [390]: list1=sorted(random.randint(0,1000) for r in range(4000))

In [391]: list2=np.random.randint(2000, size=2000)

In [392]: %timeit np.array([1 if (feat in list2) else 0 for feat in list1])
10 loops, best of 3: 102 ms per loop

In [393]: list2=set(list2)

In [394]: %timeit np.array([1 if (feat in list2) else 0 for feat in list1])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.42 ms per loop
```

Another thing to do would be to avoid repeating lookups for the same element in `list1` by saving in a dictionary the results for the elements that have already been seen. In this way you take care of duplicates in `list1`.

```
In [395]: def get_feature_list():
     ...:     d=dict.fromkeys(list2,1)
     ...:     feature_list2=[]
     ...:     for f in list1:
     ...:         if f not in d:
     ...:             d[f]=int(f in list2)
     ...:         feature_list2.append(d[f])
     ...:     return np.array(feature_list2)
     ...:

In [396]: %timeit get_feature_list()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.46 ms per loop
```

Using an extra dictionary to store results doesn't seem to bring any improvement though. This might be due to the extra overhead of creating a dictionary.

With a new function similar to the one above there is an improvement in running time but only for very large arrays

```
In [440]: def get_feature_list():
     ...:     d=[]
     ...:     feature_list2=[]
     ...:     for f in list1:
     ...:         if f not in list2:
     ...:             if f not in d:
     ...:                 d.append(f)
     ...:                 feature_list2.append(0)
     ...:             else:
     ...:                 feature_list2.append(1)
     ...:     return np.array(feature_list2)
     ...:

In [441]: list1=sorted(random.randint(0,1000) for r in range(400000))

In [443]: %timeit np.array([1 if (feat in list2) else 0 for feat in list1])
1 loop, best of 3: 273 ms per loop

In [442]: %timeit get_feature_list()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.6 s per loop
```

Another thing that could be done would be to remove an element from `list2` after it's been found, so that the size `list2` decreases at each step.

Right now I can't think of a way of exploiting the fact that `list1` is sorted to improve efficiency.